# nest build fails because of ts errors in @nestjs/config

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, nestjs-config

I am getting multiple errors about @nestjs/config, leading `npm build` command to fail but `npm run start:dev` despite showing errors is working properly. below are the screenshots from the errors and the environment.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your Typescript dependency. `@nestjs/config` uses 4.3.5 to build the package.